# The most intelligent individual in our universe joins a society with a crowd of his correspondents in many alternate universes

Tags: history-of, parallel-universe

This trope has been well known recently in the animated series *Rick & Morty* which depicts a mega-space habitat populated by millions of Ricks ruled by a Council.

[image: The Council of Ricks]

I don't know of many precedents for this idea. From what I recall, there is a very similar situation in several issues of Jonathan Hickamn's version of Marvel's *Fantastic Four* comic from about 2009, where Reed Richards, arguably the smartest human in the Marvel Comics Universe encounters a large organization of Reeds from alternate Universes.

[image: Some members of the "Council of Reeds"]

When and where, in comics or television, film or F&SF literature, was this idea first published?

Comment: The trope you are looking for is "[Alliance of Alternates](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AllianceOfAlternates)"; you can search there for the earliest.  The council of the Reeds above is noted, as is the Rick & Morty council.

Comment: @davidW this also specifies that its a) a smart character and b) an actual organisation

Comment: @DavidW TV tropes articles tend not to be very complete, especially when it comes to older fiction, so you can't trust the earliest on one of their lists is the actual earliest. I know Alan Moore used the tropes of meetings of alternate selves in various works not listed on that page, like the [many versions of Darius Dax in *Supreme*](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/daxia/4020-62964/) or the [Captain Britain Corps](https://britishcomics.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_Britain_Corps) first seen in his story "Judgement Day" from *The Daredevils* #6 (1983).

Comment: @AncientSwordRage The "alliance" part means that it's organized, and as to the first I didn't claim that _everything_ on the page was a match, just that this page included many possible matches.  The page image is a colony of Batmen.

Comment: @Hypnosifl This really isn't a thing outside of comics, because most SF treatments of alternate universes are sufficiently realistic that the same person doesn't arise in 2 universes that split much before they were born.  The closest I can think of is Pohl's *The Coming of the Quantum Cats* but the various Dominics/Nicks etc. are _very_ different from one another, and don't work together.  (And the universes had very recent split points, IIRC.)

Comment: @DavidW I agree we probably won't find an example of this trope outside comics especially given the 'most intelligent individual' criterion, but the Darius Dax example wasn't on the TV Tropes list (I see now that the Captain Britain Corps was), and that might actually fit the OP's criteria since Darius Dax was a Lex Luthor pastiche and therefore depicted as extremely intelligent. And that example [debuted in 1999](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/supreme-the-return-2-a-world-of-his-own/4000-130799/) so it may predate any of the TV Tropes examples that involve super-smart characters.

Comment: "The Man Who Folded Himself" is a 1973 science fiction novel by American writer David Gerrold.  Due to the way time travel works there are dozens if not hundreds of the protagonist that get bored  and choose to spend time with variants of themselves in an exclusive resort .  It's not really an answer because it's probably not first - and the main character is not the smartest.  But it would be like if the Ricks decided a Rick-orgy wasn't gay if it was just another Rick.  And Morty was Rick in the past - and so were his parents.  And in some timelines Rick is a woman.

Comment: Also probably not first, but in the first book of the Danish comic book series *Dimensionsdetektiven*, the hero, a private investigator, is summoned to a meeting of his alternates from various alternate realities, one of whom invented a machine (disguised as a car) that can move between realities (and hence must be very smart). One of these alternates have been murdered, and our hero is summoned to solve the crime and ultimately gets away with the dimension-travelling car. http://titlevision.dk/dimdet.htm